# How would you count the amount of digits of an integer?

Tags: java

I need a method to count the number of digits a particular integer has. It also should work for negativ numbers. Any ideas?

Comment: How would you solve the problem on paper?

Answer (score 6):

Try this code. It uses logarithm to the base of 10:

```
public static int length(int integer) {
    if(integer==0) {
        return 1;
    } else if(integer<0) {
        return ((int)Math.log10(Math.abs(integer)))+1;
    } else {
        return ((int)Math.log10(integer))+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice and efficient. You could replace `return ((int)Math.log10(Math.abs(integer)))+1;` by `return ((int)Math.log10(-integer)) + 1;`

Comment: 0 is one digit. The _real_ question is: is `-2` two digits or only one? :-)

Comment: changed the return value to 1 for the case of 0.

Comment: This will fail with Integer.MIN_VALUE. Commonly overlooked edge case: Integer.MIN_VALUE == -Integer.MIN_VALUE.

Answer (score 5):

```
(n < 0) ? String.valueOf(n).length() - 1 : String.valueOf(n).length();
```

Comment: Just need to check if `number` is less than 0. Not the String value. :)

Comment: `-` will count as a digit so should be something like `number < 0 ? String.valueof(number).length() - 1 : String.valueof(number).length();`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, fixed these cases.

Comment: What about zero? Rather a philosophical question ... ;-)

Comment: `0` is one digit in my opinion and that is what this code produces in such case :)

Answer (score 3):

Absolute value function get rid of the `-` if exist, then the remaining is similar to other answers.

```
String.valueOf(Math.abs(number)).length();
```

Answer (score 2):

fastest way:

```
    public final static int[] sizeTable = { 9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999, 999999,
        9999999, 99999999, 999999999, Integer.MAX_VALUE };

    public static int getSize(int d) {
    if (d == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        return 10;
    if (d < 0) {
        d = -d;
    }
    for (int i = 0;; i++)
        if (d <= sizeTable[i])
            return i + 1;
}
```

It is inspired by the `Integer`:

```
 static int stringSize(int x) {
    for (int i=0; ; i++)
        if (x <= sizeTable[i])
            return i+1;
}
```

Comment: Faster than this would be a binary search, but not really worth it :)

Comment: Fails with Integer.MIN_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
digitCount = String.valueof(number).length();
if(number < 0 ) digitCount--;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Integer i=new Integer(340);
      if(i<0)
      System.out.println(i.toString().length()-1);
      else
          System.out.println(i.toString().length());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test
{
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
         int n = 423;
         int count = 0;

         while(n != 0) 
         {
             n = n / 10;
             count++;
         }
         System.out.println(count);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int integerLength(int n)
{
 return Math.abs(n).toString().length();
}
```

Comment: Fails with Integer.MIN_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

Counting digits by dividing until zero remains (this can be easily adapted for any radix, or for long by just changing the argument declaration).

```
public static int countDigitsDiv(int value) {
    if (value == 0)
        return 1;
    int result = 0;
    // we work with negative values to avoid surprises with Integer.MIN_VALUE
    if (value > 0)
        value = -value;
    // count the number of digits
    while (value < 0) {
        result += 1;
        value /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using Math.log10() (This will not work properly if value is redeclared as long due to double's limited precision):

```
public static int countDigitsLog(int value) {
    int result = 1;
    if (value > 0) {
        result += (int) Math.log10(value);
    } else if (value < 0) {
        result += (int) Math.log10(-((double) value));
    }
    return result;
}
```